# condicional ternaria, pero binaria

Tags: javascript, operador, operador-ternario

Existe, en JS, algo así como un operador condicional ternario pero que únicamente tenga la expresión de resultado para true, como se muestra abajo.

```
//operador condicional ternario tradicional
condición ? expr1 : expr2;

//operador condicional hipotético
condición ? expr1;
```

Puede ejemplificarse como un atajo a esta manera de escribir el if:

```
if(condicion) { exp1 }
```

Comment: `condicion && 'si condicion es verdadero'`

Comment: Si el if contiene una sola instrucción, puede ir sin llaves. No te vuelvas loco intentando hacer el código lo más corto posible.

Comment: @Lobos creo que amerita tu respuesta. Solo para complementar, y asumiendo que la condición es booleana también podrías aplicar: condicion || 'si condición es falso';

Comment: @Lobos, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Eso era lo que necesitaba saber exactamente. Es de mucha utilidad lo que dice Mateo también, no lo sabía. Gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez quieras hacer short circuit asi:

```js
let condicion = true;
let expr1 = {
  name: 'your name'
  ... anything
  };

let resultado = condicion && expr1;
```

entonces el valor de la variable resultado seria el valor q tenga expr1. Si condicion = false, el valor de la variable resultado es también false

Comment: entonces con el operador OR || se puede lograr ejecutar una respuesta a la condición solo si esta tiene resultado negativo. Perfecto, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Let variable = true

variable ? variable = !variable  :  variable

el operador ternario dice que despues del signo de pregunta se usa como el If, si la variable es verdadera entonces ejecuta lo contrario a lo que almacena la variable, sino deja la variable como esta.

sino podes hacer esto.. si la variable es si o si true y ya lo sabes entonces..

varaible ? "es verdadero" : null.

al pasarle null no hace nada. por ende ejecuta el true

Answer (score 0):

El operador condicional ternario es el único operador en JavaScript que tiene tres operandos, como se muestra en la docu de js, no puede tener una sola condición, siempre tiene que contemplar el else.